# How to make elements of a 2d-list capital from the given index?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I want to make elements of a 2d list in capital from the index returned by a function. For example:

```
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','x','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat',
```

Then my function should return:

```
[['s','d','o','g'],['C','u','c','m'],['A','x','a','t'],['T','e','t','k']]
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords, word):
    x=zip(*crosswords)
    #print x
    for row in x:
        join_list = "".join(row)
        if join_list.find(word) != -1:
            return [row.index(word[0]),x.index(row)]
            break
    def find_word_horizontal(crosswords, word):

    for row in crosswords:
        join_list = "".join(row)
        if join_list.find(word) != -1:
            return [crosswords.index(row), row.index(word[0])]
            break

def capitalize_word_in_crossword(crosswords,word):

    if find_word_horizontal or find_word_vertical is not None:
        for i in word:
            for j in crosswords:
                if i in j:
                    i.upper() 
                    return crosswords
```

Here's what the result is:

```
[['s', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['c', 'u', 'c', 'm'], ['a', 'c', 'a', 't'], ['t', 'e', 't', 'k']]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the horizontal and vertical occurrences using list comprehension.

The horizontal occurrences are:

```
>>> filter(
    lambda (_, j): j > -1,
    [(i, ''.join(w).find(word)) for i, w in enumerate(crosswords)])
[]
```

The vertical occurrences are:

```
>>> filter(
    lambda (i, _): i > -1,
    [(''.join(w[j] for w in crosswords).find(word), j) for j in range(len(crosswords))])
[(1, 0), (1, 2)]
```

With the occurrences, it's easy to choose what to do with them (select on or all, prefer horizontal to vertical, etc.), including capitalizing them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want capital elements only for the first match. My function accepts a 2-dimensional list of characters (like a crossword puzzle) and a string (word) as input arguments. This function searches the rows and columns of the 2d list to find a match for the word. If a match is found, this functions capitalizes the matched characters in 2-dimensional list and returns the list. My function should return  [['s','d','o','g'],['C','u','c','m'],['A','x','a','t'],['T','e','t','k']]

Comment: So the reason the 'C' is capitalized is that it's the first 'C' ever, or the first 'C' in the row?

Comment: My helper function find_word_horizontal returns index [2,1]. If both a horizontal and a vertical match is found then only select the horizontal match. So, you have to do something like first go to the index and then start capitalizing the words in index [2,1],[2,2],[2,3]. Hence getting words in capital 'C','A','T' respective to the index. You have to do the same for vertical match if no horizontal match found and for that you have to loop over the column rather than the raw in horizontal match.